# overwriting parameters.ini in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have got a "locale" setting in my app/config/parameters.ini and i would like to overwrite it in my bundle.

I have tried to create parameters.ini in NewAcme/MyBundle/Resource/config/parameters.ini but it does not seem to pick this setting up.

I retrive it using $this->container->getParameter('locale') but I get original value.

Any ideas?
Big thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings in app/config are *meant* to overwrite the bundle config.

The best way to get around this is to use your own config for your bundle. See this cookbook chapter on how to do this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html